# Add() function in tf.keras.Sequential()

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

Is it possible to incorporate an Add() function in the tf.keras.Sequential() model, when defined like:

```
from tensorflow import keras

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.Input(shape(input_shape,)),
    keras.layers.Dense(32),
    keras.layers.Dense(8),
    # I want to add here
    keras.layers.Add()(some_var)
], name='my_model')
```

`some_var` is a tensor of with the same size as the network at that point. So each element needs to be added to its corresponding element in `some_var`.

I know I can do this quite easily with the functional API, but would prefer to use a sequential model as it would match other branches in my network.

If its not clear `keras.layers.Add()(some_var)` is just a guess of how I would like it to work. This gives the error: `ValueError: A merge layer should be called on a list of inputs.`.

My question is specific to the style in which I define the Sequential model.

Comment: That's not possible since by definition a sequential model is a model where each layer of it is directly connected to the previous layer; however, `Add` is a merge layer which operates on more than one input tensors. But, if `some_var` is an external constant/variable, you could instead do the addition using a `Lambda` layer and Sequential API.

Comment: Yes, it makes no sense to use Add on a Sequential model

Comment: Thanks, that did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @today comment (and then a deleted answer?!), I solved it using the `tf.keras.layer.Lambda` function.

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.Input(shape(input_shape,)),
    keras.layers.Dense(32),
    keras.layers.Dense(8),
    keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x : x + some_var)
], name='my_model')
```

Comment: Solving it like this gave me a warning: `WARNING:tensorflow:
The following Variables were used a Lambda layer's call (lambda_5), but
are not present in its tracked objects:
  <tf.Variable 'x:0' shape=() dtype=float64>
It is possible that this is intended behavior, but it is more likely
an omission. This is a strong indication that this layer should be
formulated as a subclassed Layer rather than a Lambda layer.`.

Apparently variables used in Lambda layers are not automatically tracked for gradient calculation. (https://programming.vip/docs/day-6-tensorflow2-model-subclassing-api.html)

Answer (score 1):

One of the main difference between `Functional` and `Sequential` API is that `Sequential` works with single input and single output where as `Functional` API works with single-input and single-output or single-input and multiple-output, or multiple-inputs and multiple-outputs. So using `Functional` API, you can add two layers of multiple-inputs through `keras.layers.Add().

Also, this `keras.layers.Add()` can be used in to add two input tensors which is not really we do. we can rather use like d = tf.add(a,b). Both `c` and `d` are equal

```
a = tf.constant(1.,dtype=tf.float32, shape=(1,3)).  
b = tf.constant(2.,dtype=tf.float32, shape=(1,3)). 
c = tf.keras.layers.Add()([a, b]).
```

The following example is from keras website. You can see how it is used in `Functional` API

```
import keras

input1 = keras.layers.Input(shape=(16,))
x1 = keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='relu')(input1)
input2 = keras.layers.Input(shape=(32,))
x2 = keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='relu')(input2)
# equivalent to added = keras.layers.add([x1, x2])
added = keras.layers.Add()([x1, x2])

out = keras.layers.Dense(4)(added)
model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[input1, input2], outputs=out)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand I can do it quite easily with the functional API. My question is specifically if it is possible to do this in the Sequential API.

Comment: Agree, you can use `Lambda` layer to add an `op` as  a layer. For some reason, i thought your question is aroung `Add` layer.